# How to pass useState value to getServerSideProps in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, next.js

Hi guys so I have been on this for 4 hrs trying to filter a product.
I have setState upon onClick event.
I can think of or find info on changing the query. THis is my code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    await db.connect();
    const products = await Product.find({}).lean();
    const categories = await Category.find({}).lean();
    await db.disconnect();
    return {
        props: {
            products: products.map(db.convertDocToObj),
            categories: categories.map(db.convertDocToObj),
        },
    };
}
```

I have passing the state value but nothing. I think it is to provide an variable for the state and slap it in where 'meat' is, but should i dont know if i am to make serverside request that way

```
const products = await Product.find({ category: 'meat' }).lean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getServerSideProps` usage is correct. I would bet there is something incorrect with your data fetching.

Make sure `products` and `categories` are what you think they are before returning them in `props` here. I am unfamiliar with `convertDocToObj` method but if that returns a promise you will have to resolve that before returning from `getServerSideProps`.

Once `products` and `categories` are valid they will be available as props in your component:

```js
function Page({ products, categories }) {
  // Render data...
}
```